# How to set Name value as ID in List in c# using Linq?

Tags: linq, list

> I have a one list and i want to set a Name value as ID value in same list.

Comment: Where do you fill the list? At that point set the same values for _ID_ and _Name_.

Comment: I have to fill same list. with Name and value field will be same. I have a Name value in my list and Value is null. So i have to replace null with Name field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered just iterating through the list and updating the property?

```
foreach(var element in YourList)
{
    element.Name = element.ID;
}
```

**LINQ Approach (Likely Unnecessary)**

If you absolutely had to use LINQ, you could use a [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) call to map each of your existing elements to updated versions :

```
// This assumes that YourList is a List<YourClass>
YourList = YourList.Select(x => new YourClass() { Name = x.ID, ... })
                   .ToList();;
```

It's worth noting that **LINQ is primarily used for querying and not actually updated properties / objects**, so it's likely that the loop approach would be preferred in most scenarios.

Comment: There should be no reason to use the LINQ approach, maybe without one exception: you have to create new instances and a new list for whatever reason.

Comment: I agree Tim and only included it as OP explicitly mentioned LINQ. I've added a little snippet to clarify that the preference to the looping approach.

Comment: Thanks for solution.